# react-native-share error ENSCOCOAERRORDOMAIN3072 on Save to File in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, share, react-native-ios

I'm developing a react-native application, I use `import Share from 'react-native-share';` for sharing files.

When it open share modal on iOS and I choose **Save to File** ( *for examples a pdf file* ) it thrown this execption:

```
{
        "code": "ENSCOCOAERRORDOMAIN3072",
        "message": "The operation was cancelled.",
        "nativeStackIOS": [
            "0   MyApp                               0x0000000109361a97 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 135",
            "1   MyApp                               0x00000001093619c3 RCTJSErrorFromNSError + 275",
            "2   MyApp                               0x00000001092e8c81 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_4.110 + 161",
            "3   MyApp                               0x0000000109242696 __48-[RNShare open:failureCallback:successCallback:]_block_invoke_2 + 214",
            "4   ShareSheet                          0x00007fff4310eec7 __68-[UIActivityViewController _cleanupActivityWithSuccess:items:error:]_block_invoke + 183",
            "5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46e15f25 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 978",
            "6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46e1aa61 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.503 + 199",
            "7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f32e2c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 88",
            "8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a0c180 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 247",
            "9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a0be03 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1423",
            "10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a45f20 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 671",
            "11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a16a11 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 268",
            "12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a16f83 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 259",
            "13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a1710a -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 650",
            "14  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b080ac2 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 306",
            "15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516ad781 _dispatch_client_callout + 8",
            "16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516b9caa _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1212",
            "17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0ce49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9",
            "18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b07aa9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2329",
            "19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b06e66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438",
            "20  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38346bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65",
            "21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47578dd0 UIApplicationMain + 1621",
            "22  MyApp                               0x0000000109117201 main + 97",
            "23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1",
            "24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1"
        ],
        "domain": "NSCocoaErrorDomain",
        "userInfo": {}
    }
```